# Reset web interface password on Neo4j EC2 instance

Tags: neo4j, jetty

I set up Neo4j on an EC2 instance using this

http://www.neo4j.org/develop/ec2

I have the SSH key so I can SSH into the instance, but I don't remember the password I set up for the web interface. I believe this is a Jetty basicauth equivalent, but I'm not sure, nor could I find the config files that might lead me to the right place. How can I reset this password?

Answer (score 0):

`neo4j-server.properties´ has a setting for the auth-extension being used by the puppet script:

```
org.neo4j.server.credentials=<user>:<pass>
```

I'm not sure where `neo4j-server.properties` is located on your machine, check `/etc/neo4j` or use `find / -name neo4j-server.properties`.

Comment: I have that file, but there is no such line in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset neo4j web interface password by following these steps, provided you have SSH access to ec2 instance:

1. Login to ec2 instance from your local console:

   `ssh -i [your-key] ubuntu@[ec2-instance-ip]`
2. login as superuser `sudo su`
3. Remove auth file from  `var/lib/neoj/data/dbms`

   `rm -f var/lib/neoj/data/dbms/auth`
4. Reset the password by running

   `neo4j-admin set-initial-password secret`
5. Restart neo4j: `systemctl restart neo4j`

You can access neo4j web interface from browser with username as neo4j and new password.